# Hypercube Graph Star Coverings

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory

What is the minimum number of star graphs $S_4$ required to fully cover a 4-dimensional hypercube graph $Q_4$? How about the number of $S_5$ star graphs necessary to cover the 5-dimensional hypercube graph $Q_5$? Finally, what about the 
6-dimensional case?

For the 4-dimensional case, I keep getting that we need $4$ star graphs, but what if there's a way to cover it with $3$ star graphs? I don't have an algorithmic approach, and honestly, drawing these higher-dimension hypercubes is an arduous task. Could someone propose how to attain those coverings?

Comment: I think this could be equivalent to finding the dominating set of those hypercubes. However, I'm not sure what the standard algorithm is for finding dominating sets... See more at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DominatingSet.html

Answer (score 1):

$Q_n$ has $n 2^{n-1}$ edges and $S_n$ has $n$ edges, therefore at least 
$\frac{n 2^{n-1}}{n} = 2^{n-1}$ $S_n$ are needed to cover the edges of the cube.

Also, $Q_n$ is bipartite graph. Each vertex and its incident edges forms a an $S_n$ of $Q_n$. If you take the vertices of one part and their incident edges you get exactly $2^{n-1}$ stars $S_n$ that cover all the edges of $Q_n$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, http://oeis.org/A000983 shows the correct number for small values. Are you sure that exactly $2^{n-1}$ are needed to cover all the edges of $Q_n$?

Comment: This is for covering all the edges. The other is for dominating sets I believe. They are different.

Comment: I believe that the author of this post is asking about dominating sets... I'm not sure how to answer the question about dominating sets. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: What is being cover it here? Vertices or edges?